# Create / edit a GPO for setting the startup script

Tags: powershell-3.0, gpo

I need to write a powershell script to create a GPO for setting a logon script.

I am able to create a GPO using New-GPO. However, I have a script in place.

So have to set the logon script under 
`Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Scripts` (Startup/Shutdown) through powershell..

Comment: You should share the code you already have.

Comment: import-module grouppolicy
New-GPO -Name <name> -comment "<name>"